# Import with Two Files and both need the import

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import

I have two py files and have simplified my problem of just a few lines.

One:

```
from Two import PrintTwo

class PrintOne(object):
    print('HelloOne')
```

Two:

```
from One import PrintOne

class PrintTwo(object):

    print('HelloTwo')
```

This brings up this message: cannot import name 'PrintTwo' as expected.

But my problem is I need to use some functions of these classes in both files.

I cant find a solution for that, how is the correct workflow for a case like this?

Kind regards

Comment: you are creating a circular import. in order to mix and match like that these classes need to be declared together, I'm not convinced that there is any other "proper" solution

Comment: declared together means in one file?

Comment: yes, depending on how you intend to use the methods from each file there are other workarounds, but they are not good practice, such as instead of imports at the start of the file, import just before you need it (inside functions or class functions that are not executed at time of import) but this doesn't allow you to do things like subclassing

Comment: Thank you! Is it a good solution to have a third file lets call it 'Transfer' where I handle all the data which is exchanged through the files?

Comment: adding a third file doesn't really solve anything, because you still have separate namespaces inside each file, your only solutions are to either put both classes into a single file, or as dominique's answer you use lazy importing, but as stated before this means you cannot use those imported classes to subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **circular importing** and they can work, if you set them up properly. However, I'd not recommend using circular imports and rather refactor the code.

It's hard to say what to change on the code, if I don't see it. When I experience circular imports then I try to avoid them by refactoring the code. Possible solutions are:

- Move bits of the "shared" code into an own Python module (recommended)
- Lazy import a module/component, means only import it when you use it (works but not really shiny)

I can't show you an example based on the code above, because you only circular import the modules but don't use them.

As mentioned before, a workaround is using imports only when you use them, for example:

```
class PrintOne:

    def some_magic_method(self):
        from Two import PrintTwo
```

Comment: You helped me a lot! I was pretty unsure if making a third python file would be recommended or just making my problems bigger. Now, with the solution in mind, I can move on. And especially search for the right things!

Comment: You're welcome. It's OK to create a third python file in that case, most likely recommended (without seeing the code) :)